# Link to app will not open in Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, browser, app-market-link

I am using the URI format `http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>` described in [Linking to Your Apps on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent) in order to open the app in Android Market or Google Play to install it. But it only opens it in the browser as it would do it on the desktop. And when `Install` is clicked it asks the user to sign-in to install.

How can I link the app in Google Play so the user can install it?

Comment: This is weird, since on my device the browser straight up refuses to open Market links and opens the Market app.  I would go to `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications` and clear the defaults for the browser to ensure that isn't causing the problem.  If that doesn't work: What device do you have?  Have you tried typing the URL directly into the browser and seeing what happens?  Where is this link appearing, exactly?  (On a web page or in another app?)

Comment: @MatthewRead I've tried to used the link from a message, QR code, email,... And same thing. Also, I've tried on different android devices, not just one, and same issue.

Comment: Try replacing http with https. It may look dumb, but try it.

Comment: @SachinShekhar I used both `http` and `https`. Even `market`. And the same result.

Comment: What's your web browser? Default Android browser and Dolphin HD automatically redirect to Play Store app (or, atleast ask)...

Comment: Did you get solution for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try directly this if link is originated from an app for Android to handle:

`market://details?id=<package_name>`

Note: There's no domain and host.

Comment: Interesting that this way works. It directs to the market place properly. Thanks.

Comment: This'll only work on the Android device. Trying this in a desktop browser won't work.

Comment: @AlEverett Unless there's a market protocol handler in desktop browser to insert domain and host. :)

Comment: In fact, it doesn't work even in Android web browsers. Its intended to use in app development.

Comment: Then if this is an app development question it's in the wrong place.

Comment: @AlEverett Can't be said as asker didn't mention that. Android has system-wide protocol handler for this. So, I believe, it can be used with Tasker etc too.

Comment: Initially, I assumed different thing (see my comments on question). Then, I got the clue from asker's comment on other question: The link is accessed from device.

Comment: @SachinShekhar The link is stored in a QR code as well as redirected form a website. It is accessed through a QR code reader from a device. Therefore, I don't believe it has anything with development.

Comment: @slybloty Thanks for the clarification. I was curious as you didn't mention development anywhere.

Comment: And, it has opened new usage domain for me. Thanks again.. :)

Comment: This only works for Android devices. How can you make it work for both mobile and desktop browsers regardless of operating system, given that when on Android I want to open the Google Play store app and not the web browser?

Comment: To combine best of both worlds, set URL of the link to `http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>` and then change it in JS if on Android - see my answer below http://android.stackexchange.com/a/164307/165570

Answer (score 7):

I'm using the code below and it is working fine with my phone and emulator.

For the phone with Google Play app, it will automatically open the app.
For the emulator (without Google Play app), it will automatically open the browser.

```
try { 
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example"));
  startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e) { //google play app is not installed
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example"));
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: +1 for try/catch. In fact sometimes if there is no Google Play app installed on device, we'll get crash when try to open an app with URL starts with "market://details?id="

Answer (score 1):

First off, the user can actually install the app from the market. He just can't do it directly but only make Google remote-install the app via the website, as he would do if he browsed the market on his PC.

Second, what browser are you testing this with? Opera isn't well integrated into Android and won't open Play URLs in the app. In fact I'm not sure even the native browser will.

Maybe you should just use `market://` links instead of `http://`links.

Comment: It's the android browser it opens with instead of the app. The link is accessed from the device. I want the user to be able to install the app by clicking the link and be directed to Market or Google Play.

Answer (score 1):

Settings > Applications > All (top tab)
Click Menu button > Reset app preferences

Source:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zt_alKha_-s

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 0):

I found simple and easy solution.

1. make a html page any where.
   `<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0; URL=market://details?id=package_name" />`
2. Open browser and type this html URL
3. you will see your app in play market app

Answer (score 0):

To have a solution that works in a best possible way for desktop/Android/mobile non-Android:

HTML:

```
<a id="play-store-link" href="http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$PACKAGE_NAME">
```

JS:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i)) {
    document.getElementById('play-store-link').href = 'market://details?id=$PACKAGE_NAME';
}
```

Comment: but this don't work with Opera browser

Answer (score 0):

Using the market:// because it is not a web link and won't work on all Android devices

Use this link https://play.app.goo.gl/?link=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp

Replace the com.myapp with your app's